# Ruby - Time.now.to_date.next_month.begin gives error instead of first of next month

Tags: ruby, datetime, date, time

When I use:

```
require 'date'
Time.now.to_date.next_month
```

it returns

```
 => #<Date: 2012-07-29 ((2456138j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

If I try tab completion for `Time.now.to_date.next_month.` I see:

```
1.9.3p194 :081 > Time.now.to_date.next_month.be
Time.now.to_date.next_month.begin     Time.now.to_date.next_month.between?
```

But if I try `Time.now.to_date.next_month.begin` I get

```
1.9.3p194 :081 > Time.now.to_date.next_month.begin
NoMethodError: undefined method `begin' for #<Date: 2012-07-29 ((...
```

Why is that?

Comment: `begin` is a keyword in Ruby that starts off an exception block. As to why irb suggests it, I don't know.

Comment: Try also Asdfsc.new.be or Dafdc.new.en  )) It just the way it works)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are instantiating and asking for a suggestion in the same line.

```
Time.now.to_date.next_month.be<tab> #=> contains "begin"

t = Time.now.to_date.next_month
t.be<tab> #=> Does not contain "begin"
```

Since the Ruby interpreter has not processed the expression, it has no idea what kind of class it is dealing with and hence when you `<tab>`, it is just giving you everything.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of function-overloading. When you have any concerns, first look the API reference and then ask the question.

The first date of next month is not returned because there is no such function in Date. There are total 719 functions defined on all objects, try to press tab on any  and begin and between happens to be such function.

The core assumption that "IRB auto_complete is guarantee that the function is what you want it to be" is completely misguided and wrong.

Comment: But he is not getting an ArgumentError. Plus, `Date` has neither of these as an ancestor.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell **The first date of next month is not returned because there is no such function in Date**. There are total 719 functions defined on all objects, try to press tab on any <var_name> and begin and between happens to be such function. We can argue for at any length, but the core assumption that "*IRB auto_complete is guarantee that the function is what you want it to be*" is completely misguided and wrong. I would still say RTFM

Comment: I tried `x = "hi"; x.be` and then tabbed. `between` was the only thing that showed up. (fyi, I'm not the one that down voted you)

Comment: Just try **asdf.<tab>** or any undeclared name. when you say x="string" you are providing additional information to IRB about the object and hence not seeing begins. BTW i don't care about down votes ;)